# How can I generate a web page that checks the status of a process or service?

Tags: apache

I have a dedicated server that runs a few lightweight game servers. The server is already running Apache. However I am cheap and the server hardware is not exactly robust and not all the servers we use run concurrently. I want to be able to generate a web page say /stats that has some info like:

```
Game 1: Online <uptime>
Game 2: Offline
...etc
```

I'm certain that I could run a script using a cronjob that just uses ps + grep logged into a file, and then parse that file for information on the server but I'm looking for a more dynamic option that checks as the page is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least a few options (other people may have additional suggestions beyond what is listed here):

1. Cron a shell script to generate a stats.html or stats.txt
2. PHP's `shell_exec` (could run `ps |grep...` for example) or `exec`
3. PHP's variety of `posix` functions may help (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.posix.php)
4. If you have PERL available there may be a few options there as well

My suggestion is to evaluate `shell_exec` or `exec` before any of the others.

If you need additional assistance please post what you have tried and the results.

Comment: I hadn't even started yet. I was wondering what my options were first. I think the best option here is the second one you mentioned. I was thinking PHP would be my answer but as I mentioned before I'm not very familiar with it and wasn't sure what my options were. `shell_exec` seems to be what I was looking for.